# Каким методом в ОС Linux Ubuntu мониторить работу x-сервера, и lightdm, при ступоре, их перезапуская

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lightdm

Иногда графика виснет полностью, клавиатура отказывает, при этом музыка может продолжать играть. Нужно отследить такое зависание, (пропинговать) и выполнить команду unity --replace, если не помогает то sudo service lightdm restart либо

Comment: обычное решение в таких случаях — разобраться, когда/почему «виснут» X-ы и исключить это.... отслеживание потребует дополнительного исследования «что работает в таких случаях, а что нет» и уже на основе этого думать об отслеживании...

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Nagios, если я правильно помню как называется.